# Raspberry-pi using hardware resistor, need schema confirmation (newbie)

Tags: resistors, raspberry-pi, gpio

Good morning,

I learn electronics from raspberry-pi hardware. I realized the following diagram to help me understand 'PULL-UP' using the internal resistor to the hardware.(Python code here)

Could someone just confirm that I'm not mistaken somewhere and that my next schema is valid ? Thank you for your time and your indulgence (I just start with two three bases)

[image]

Comment: Sorry if I am being daft. Whats the question?

Comment: no problem, i have realized this diagram for learn about pull-up  using internal resistor. I need help for diagram validation . (I have understand pull-up or i have not understand pull-up using hardware resistor ?)

Comment: Note that pin 3 on GPIO connector of Raspberry Pi is not ground, unless you drive it low. You probably want pin 6.

Comment: Indeed, very well seen! thank you ! (Error only on the diagram)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks OK, at least you seem to understand how a pull-up works. The only issue is that the pull-up is never "10", maybe you mean "10 k".

In a real circuit these days it will not actually be a resistor, but a *pull-up circuit* made from a transistor. The effect is the same though. The datasheet will often have details on this.

Comment: Oh yes i have read it for the 10K resistor , thank's you very much

Comment: 'these days it will not actually be a resistor' .... Can I know what replaces it please, otherwise I will look

Comment: Internal pull-ups in microcontrollers are semiconductors acting as resistors that can be turned on and off in software. If you are using an external pull-up, just use a regular resistor.

Comment: @Aborted-Security Updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for this informations and your time.